# changing to std::vector causing segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault

Hello so i have a struct that allocate memory using new keyword and i wanted to remove by using std::vector instead so i did like this

**before changing to std::vector**

```
BYTE* packPlayerMoving(PlayerMoving* dataStruct)
{
    BYTE* data = new BYTE[56];
    for (int i = 0; i < 56; i++)
    {
        data[i] = 0;
    }
    memcpy(data, &dataStruct->packetType, 4);
    memcpy(data + 4, &dataStruct->netID, 4);
    memcpy(data + 12, &dataStruct->characterState, 4);
    memcpy(data + 20, &dataStruct->plantingTree, 4);
    memcpy(data + 24, &dataStruct->x, 4);
    memcpy(data + 28, &dataStruct->y, 4);
    memcpy(data + 32, &dataStruct->XSpeed, 4);
    memcpy(data + 36, &dataStruct->YSpeed, 4);
    memcpy(data + 44, &dataStruct->punchX, 4);
    memcpy(data + 48, &dataStruct->punchY, 4);
    return data;
}
```

```
void SendPacketRaw(int a1, void *packetData, size_t packetDataSize, void *a4, ENetPeer* peer, int packetFlag)
{
    ENetPacket *p;

    if (peer) // check if we have it setup
    {
        if (a1 == 4 && *((BYTE *)packetData + 12) & 8)
        {
            p = enet_packet_create(0, packetDataSize + *((DWORD *)packetData + 13) + 5, packetFlag);
            int four = 4;
            memcpy(p->data, &four, 4);
            memcpy((char *)p->data + 4, packetData, packetDataSize);
            memcpy((char *)p->data + packetDataSize + 4, a4, *((DWORD *)packetData + 13));
            enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p);
        }
        else
        {
            p = enet_packet_create(0, packetDataSize + 5, packetFlag);
            memcpy(p->data, &a1, 4);
            memcpy((char *)p->data + 4, packetData, packetDataSize);
            enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p);
        }
    }
    delete (char*)packetData;
}
```

**after changing to std::vector**

```
std::vector<BYTE> packPlayerMoving(PlayerMoving *dataStruct)
{
    std::vector<BYTE> data(56);
    memcpy(&data[0], &dataStruct->packetType, 4);
    memcpy(&data[4], &dataStruct->netID, 4);
    memcpy(&data[12], &dataStruct->characterState, 4);
    memcpy(&data[20], &dataStruct->plantingTree, 4);
    memcpy(&data[24], &dataStruct->x, 4);
    memcpy(&data[28], &dataStruct->y, 4);
    memcpy(&data[32], &dataStruct->XSpeed, 4);
    memcpy(&data[36], &dataStruct->YSpeed, 4);
    memcpy(&data[44], &dataStruct->punchX, 4);
    memcpy(&data[48], &dataStruct->punchY, 4);
    return data;
}
```

```
void SendPacketRaw(int a1, std::vector<BYTE> packetData, size_t packetDataSize, void *a4, ENetPeer *peer, int packetFlag)
{
    ENetPacket *p;

    if (peer) // check if we have it setup
    {
        if (a1 == 4 && *(&packetData[12]) & 8)
        {
            p = enet_packet_create(0, packetDataSize + *(&packetData[13]) + 5, packetFlag);
            int four = 4;
            memcpy(p->data, &four, 4);
            memcpy((char *)p->data + 4, &packetData[0], packetDataSize);
            void * a4 = 0;
            memcpy((char *)p->data + packetDataSize + 4,  a4, *(&packetData[13]));
            enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p);
        }
        else
        {
            p = enet_packet_create(0, packetDataSize + 5, packetFlag);
            memcpy(p->data, &a1, 4);
            memcpy((char *)p->data + 4, &packetData[0], packetDataSize);
            enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p);
        }
    }
}
```

and i use in this way :

```
SendPacketRaw(4, packPlayerMoving(&data), 56, 0, currentPeer, ENET_PACKET_FLAG_RELIABLE);
```

ok so my problem is before i convert it to std::vector it was working fine without issues
but after i converted it i started getting segmentation fault what am i doing wrong ?

and here valgrind output

```
==12418== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12418==    at 0x1189D7: SendPacketRaw(int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, unsigned long, void*, _ENetPeer*, int) (utils.cpp:172)
==12418==    by 0x11E337: Nothing(_ENetPeer*, int, int) (worlds.cpp:405)
==12418==    by 0x1208AD: Events::Recieve(_ENetHost*, _ENetPacket*, _ENetPeer*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (events.cpp:315)
==12418==    by 0x123BDB: Run() (main.cpp:62)
==12418==    by 0x123C85: main (main.cpp:87)
==12418== 
==12418== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12418==    at 0x1450E7: enet_packet_create (in /home/cmd/Desktop/PRC++/server)
==12418==    by 0x118A20: SendPacketRaw(int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, unsigned long, void*, _ENetPeer*, int) (utils.cpp:174)
==12418==    by 0x11E337: Nothing(_ENetPeer*, int, int) (worlds.cpp:405)
==12418==    by 0x1208AD: Events::Recieve(_ENetHost*, _ENetPacket*, _ENetPeer*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (events.cpp:315)
==12418==    by 0x123BDB: Run() (main.cpp:62)
==12418==    by 0x123C85: main (main.cpp:87)
==12418== 
==12418== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12418==    at 0x48429FA: memmove (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12418==    by 0x118AA8: SendPacketRaw(int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, unsigned long, void*, _ENetPeer*, int) (utils.cpp:179)
==12418==    by 0x11E337: Nothing(_ENetPeer*, int, int) (worlds.cpp:405)
==12418==    by 0x1208AD: Events::Recieve(_ENetHost*, _ENetPacket*, _ENetPeer*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (events.cpp:315)
==12418==    by 0x123BDB: Run() (main.cpp:62)
==12418==    by 0x123C85: main (main.cpp:87)
==12418== 
==12418== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12418==    at 0x4842BA1: memmove (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12418==    by 0x118AA8: SendPacketRaw(int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, unsigned long, void*, _ENetPeer*, int) (utils.cpp:179)
==12418==    by 0x11E337: Nothing(_ENetPeer*, int, int) (worlds.cpp:405)
==12418==    by 0x1208AD: Events::Recieve(_ENetHost*, _ENetPacket*, _ENetPeer*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (events.cpp:315)
==12418==    by 0x123BDB: Run() (main.cpp:62)
==12418==    by 0x123C85: main (main.cpp:87)
==12418== 
==12418== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==12418==    at 0x4842B0E: memmove (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12418==    by 0x118AA8: SendPacketRaw(int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, unsigned long, void*, _ENetPeer*, int) (utils.cpp:179)
==12418==    by 0x11E337: Nothing(_ENetPeer*, int, int) (worlds.cpp:405)
==12418==    by 0x1208AD: Events::Recieve(_ENetHost*, _ENetPacket*, _ENetPeer*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (events.cpp:315)
==12418==    by 0x123BDB: Run() (main.cpp:62)
==12418==    by 0x123C85: main (main.cpp:87)
==12418== 
==12418== Invalid read of size 2
==12418==    at 0x4842B30: memmove (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12418==    by 0x118AA8: SendPacketRaw(int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, unsigned long, void*, _ENetPeer*, int) (utils.cpp:179)
==12418==    by 0x11E337: Nothing(_ENetPeer*, int, int) (worlds.cpp:405)
==12418==    by 0x1208AD: Events::Recieve(_ENetHost*, _ENetPacket*, _ENetPeer*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (events.cpp:315)
==12418==    by 0x123BDB: Run() (main.cpp:62)
==12418==    by 0x123C85: main (main.cpp:87)
==12418==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12418== 
==12418== 
==12418== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==12418==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==12418==    at 0x4842B30: memmove (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12418==    by 0x118AA8: SendPacketRaw(int, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >, unsigned long, void*, _ENetPeer*, int) (utils.cpp:179)
==12418==    by 0x11E337: Nothing(_ENetPeer*, int, int) (worlds.cpp:405)
==12418==    by 0x1208AD: Events::Recieve(_ENetHost*, _ENetPacket*, _ENetPeer*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (events.cpp:315)
==12418==    by 0x123BDB: Run() (main.cpp:62)
==12418==    by 0x123C85: main (main.cpp:87)
==12418==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==12418==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==12418==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==12418==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==12418==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==12418== 
==12418== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12418==     in use at exit: 11,557,918 bytes in 22,893 blocks
==12418==   total heap usage: 94,578 allocs, 71,685 frees, 29,567,151 bytes allocated
==12418== 
==12418== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12418==    definitely lost: 1,312 bytes in 4 blocks
==12418==    indirectly lost: 5,711 bytes in 17 blocks
==12418==      possibly lost: 224 bytes in 2 blocks
==12418==    still reachable: 11,550,671 bytes in 22,870 blocks
==12418==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12418== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==12418== 
==12418== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==12418== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==12418== ERROR SUMMARY: 45563 errors from 34 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: if you allocate with `new BYTE[]` you need to deallocate with `delete [] (BYTE*)`, but this isn't your problem

Comment: Do you know how to use a debugger?

Comment: `BYTE* data = new BYTE[56];` vs `std::vector<BYTE> data(64);`: why different number?

Comment: not really idk how to use debugger

Comment: `*(&packetData[x])` is usually written `packetData[x]`.

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal example, that can be compiled and produces the error? It is easier to point out where the error is, if a short, yet complete code is provided instead of trying to understand your code in deep.

Comment: My advice is to spend 20 minutes and learn how to use your debugger. It will save you many hours in the long run. Also if you are to become a programmer you will not succeed if you can not debug code.

Comment: `*((DWORD *)packetData + 13)` in the first is not the same as `*(&packetData[13])` in the second.

Comment: where is line `utils.cpp:172`? Valgrind signals that some condition is checked based on variable with undefined value. Then SEGFAUL is reported form `utils.cpp:179`! Where is it?

Comment: Please share [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is this line meant to be doing? `memcpy((char *)p->data + packetDataSize + 4,  a4, *(&packetData[13]));` Of what significance is `packetData[13]`?

Comment: utils:172 is this line
        if (a1 == 4 && *(&packetData[12]) & 8)
utils:179 is this line 
            enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p);

Comment: enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p); //this line is utils:179...

Comment: Nuke this code from the orbit. What is purpose of serializing something to raw data (vector or not vector) and then scan those data from this raw data. Serializing to raw data (vector) make seance just before streaming it to io device: file/network/other device.

Comment: Another mystery is why you allocate 56 bytes but only use 52 of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*((DWORD *)packetData + 13)` in your first version reads the 13th DWORD (at byte index 52).

`*(&packetData[13])` in your second version reads the 13th BYTE.

This whole code is a bit of a mess, so I'm loath just to paper over that issue, but changing the second version to:

`*(((DWORD *)packetData.data())+13)` should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your original code, inside your `SendPacketRaw()` function, you were delete-ing the `packetData` pointer parameter passed to it, while in this your modified version that second parameter `packetData` is a vector which continues to hold some data after the end of your function `SendPacketRaw()`.

I'm not sure about the use of your `SendPacketRaw()` function and the logic of managing the memory that its second parameter is supposed to maintain, but I have a gut feeling that this is the main cause of Valgrind being unhappy.

So I advise you first of all to pass that second vector parmeter `packetData` as a reference, and to clean it before finishing your function.

```
void SendPacketRaw(int a1, std::vector<BYTE> &packetData, size_t packetDataSize, void *a4, ENetPeer *peer, int packetFlag)
{
    ENetPacket *p;

    if (peer) // check if we have it setup
    {
        if (a1 == 4 && *(&packetData[12]) & 8)
        {
            p = enet_packet_create(0, packetDataSize + *(&packetData[13]) + 5, packetFlag);
            int four = 4;
            memcpy(p->data, &four, 4);
            memcpy((char *)p->data + 4, &packetData[0], packetDataSize);
            void * a4 = 0;
            memcpy((char *)p->data + packetDataSize + 4,  a4, *(&packetData[13]));
            enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p);
        }
        else
        {
            p = enet_packet_create(0, packetDataSize + 5, packetFlag);
            memcpy(p->data, &a1, 4);
            memcpy((char *)p->data + 4, &packetData[0], packetDataSize);
            enet_peer_send(peer, 0, p);
        }
    }
    
    packetData.clear();
}
```

Comment: when i try to comment this line //memcpy((char *)p->data + packetDataSize + 4,  a4, packetData[13]); i dont get segmentation fault anymore but it affect the work

Comment: @cmdocmd please try my suggested solution first and let me know if it's fine or no.

Comment: `std::vector::clear()` may, but is not obliged to free inner buffer

Comment: @cmdocmd, did you put the ```&``` mark in front of your second vector parameter to pass it by reference?

Answer (score 0):

i think i see a major bug in your code, a `std::vector<BYTE> data`  , in
`&data[0]`
if you do the address operator u get the object address as `[]` is a operator of vector class. so u may wanna use `data.data()` it'll return you a raw pointer, do this before `memcpy()` 
ps: my first answer

Comment: Nope. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence note `operator[]` is higher then `operator&`.

Comment: it doesn't matter if the &operator has higher precedence, even the above answer says the same thing , .data() will return raw pointer which is the pointer to array address .